# Missing/overlapping triangles in Delaunay Triangulation with Bowyer–Watson algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, triangulation

I'm using the Bowyer-Watson algorithm for Delaunay Triangulation and I have it almost entirely done, but there is still a small edge case in the code that causes there to be missing/overlapping triangles in the triangulation. Does anybody know what I should change to get rid of of holes/overlapping triangles in the triangulation?

```
    public ArrayList<NTriangle> triangulate() {
        //Based off this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowyer%E2%80%93Watson_algorithm

        ArrayList<NTriangle> tri = new ArrayList<NTriangle>();
        superT = new NTriangle(new NPoint(-WIDTH,HEIGHT+HEIGHT), new NPoint(WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT), new NPoint(WIDTH+WIDTH, HEIGHT+HEIGHT));

        tri.add(superT);

        for(NPoint p : origPoints) {
            ArrayList<NTriangle> badTri = new ArrayList<NTriangle>();

            for(NTriangle t : tri) {
                int dist = dist(t.circ,p);
                if(dist <= t.rad) 
                    badTri.add(t);
            }
            ArrayList<NLine> unique = new ArrayList<NLine>();
            for(NTriangle t : badTri) {
                for(NLine l : t.lines) {
                    if(!edgeInTri(badTri,l)) { // checks if the edge l is not in any of the badTri triangles
                        unique.add(l);
                    }
                }
            }
            for(NTriangle t : badTri)
                tri.remove(t);

            for(NLine l : unique) {
                NTriangle t = new NTriangle(p,l.a,l.b);
                tri.add(t);
            }
        }

        // remove everything connected to the supertringle
        ArrayList<NTriangle> remove = new ArrayList<NTriangle>();

        for(NTriangle t : tri) {
            for(NPoint p : superT.points) {
                if(contains(t.points, p))  // checks in p is in t.points
                    remove.add(t);
            }
        }

        for(NTriangle t : remove) 
            tri.remove(t);

        return tri;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for(NTriangle t : triangles )
            t.paint(g);

        for(NPoint p : origPoints)
            System.out.println(p.y);

    }
}
```

The code above in the algorithm part, I will post the objects below. Im using the wikipedia pseudocode as a guideline.

NPoint class
    package geometry;

```
public class NPoint {
    public int x, y;
    public NPoint(int x_, int y_) {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
    }

    public static NPoint multiply(NPoint n, double i) {
        return new NPoint((int)(n.x*i), (int)(n.y*i));
    }

    public static NPoint add(NPoint n, NPoint m) {
        return new NPoint((int)(n.x+m.x), (int)(n.y+m.y));
    }

    public static boolean overlap(NPoint a, NPoint b) {
        if(a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y) 
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

NLine class
    package geometry;

```
public class NLine {
    public int ax, ay;
    public int bx, by;

    public NPoint a, b;

    public NLine(int ax_, int ay_, int bx_, int by_) {
        a = new NPoint(ax, ay);
        a = new NPoint(bx, by);

        ax = ax_;
        ay = ay_;
        bx = bx_;
        by = by_;
    }

    public NLine(NPoint a_, NPoint b_) {
        this.a=a_;
        this.b=b_;
    }

    public static boolean overlap(NLine n, NLine l) {
        if((NPoint.overlap(n.a, l.a) && (NPoint.overlap(n.b, l.b))) || (NPoint.overlap(n.a, l.b) && (NPoint.overlap(n.b, l.a))))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

NTriangle class

```
package geometry;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class NTriangle {

    public NPoint a, b, c;

    public NPoint circ = new NPoint(0,0);
    public int rad = 0;

    public NPoint[] points = new NPoint[3];
    public NLine[] lines = new NLine[3];

    public NTriangle(NPoint p1_, NPoint p2_, NPoint p3_) {
        a = p1_;
        b = p2_;
        c = p3_;

        points[0] = a;
        points[1] = b;
        points[2] = c;

        lines[0] = new NLine(a,b);
        lines[1] = new NLine(a,c);
        lines[2] = new NLine(b,c);

        circumCenter(a,b,c);
    }

    public void circumCenter(NPoint p0, NPoint p1, NPoint p2) {
        float dA, dB, dC, aux1, aux2, div;

        dA = p0.x * p0.x + p0.y * p0.y;
        dB = p1.x * p1.x + p1.y * p1.y;
        dC = p2.x * p2.x + p2.y * p2.y;

        aux1 = (dA*(p2.y - p1.y) + dB*(p0.y - p2.y) + dC*(p1.y - p0.y));
        aux2 = -(dA*(p2.x - p1.x) + dB*(p0.x - p2.x) + dC*(p1.x - p0.x));
        div = (2*(p0.x*(p2.y - p1.y) + p1.x*(p0.y-p2.y) + p2.x*(p1.y - p0.y)));

        if(div == 0){ 
            return;
        }

        circ.x = (int) (aux1/div);
        circ.y = (int) (aux2/div);

        rad = (int) Math.sqrt((circ.x - p0.x)*(circ.x - p0.x) + (circ.y - p0.y)*(circ.y - p0.y));
    }

// paint function removed for readability
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There needs to be a question. Saying you're having a problem with this is too vague. What exactly are you having a problem with? What kind of question can you ask that would help you?

Comment: Sorry, Ill edit my question

Comment: Ok, that's better. It could still be more focused. Put the question first and leave out things that aren't necessary for an answer. Better yet show that you've made effort in trying to solve the problem and ask questions based on what you've done.

Comment: It's good you've put some code, but ideally you want a **M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The more code that's not directly related to the question just gives people more work trying to figure it out and how it relates to your question.

Comment: I know, but the outside classes are very small and pretty self explanatory, so I figured it was fine. The object classes can pretty much be ignored, but if someone really wants to look into it, it is there. The problem I want to avoid is putting some code then being asked for a bunch of outside classes and such after it is posted.

Comment: You want your example to be complete but if you can leave anything out then I would

Comment: Ill keep it in mind and try to cut down on some stuff here, thanks.

Comment: Dealing with corners cases is not simple. When you have a clear bug, it surfaces soon. When not, that's hard to debug meshes. I advice to draw your mesh, see where it fails, go back some steps to find the ofending point/triangle. Also be aware that you have do deal with numerical issues (your `dist` and `edgeInTri` funcs) when points are near co-linear or co-circunference, that ruin the mesh because Delaunay condition is lost. The more points, the more problably for issues.